# How do I use something other than unicode to make a plus/minus sign?

Tags: html, unicode, glyphicons

In the following HTML, how would I replace the unicode for plus sign with a non-unicode plus sign? The reason I want to replace the unicode is because I changed the color of the plus sign to white (#fff), but it still shows up as the original color (grey) in Chrome and Edge...and I read that it's because the unicode is already somehow color-encoded.

`.accordian:after {`
`content: '\02795';`
`/*Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */`
`font-size: 17px;`
`color: #fff;`
`float: right;`
`margin-left: 5px; }`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**
you can use a + inside the content instead of the unicode

**Solution 2 :**
font awesome icons can be used with pseudo elements check this :
https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).